# Less formal way of saying "I'm going offline"

Tags: phrases, slang

Imagine a situation I'm going to the subway and will lose signal any moment.

How would you tell someone you will lose signal soon? Or that you're going .. Offline essentially?

Is "going dark" the phrase?

Comment: "I'm about to lose signal."

Comment: or, quite formal,  "I'm about to lose connection (or connectivity)."

Comment: To my ear, "I'm going offline" isn't formal at all. When I want to shake things up a bit, I say something like "I will be beyond the reach of your puny technology."

Comment: I’m goin’ into the subway, I’m prolly gonna lose you in a minute.

Comment: Less formal than "*I'm going offline*"? There is nothing particularly formal about that phrase.

Comment: "I am on the verge of entering a zone of diminished radio-frequency propagation effectiveness."

Answer (score 1):

'Dropping out' has a new meaning (beyond quitting school).

Comment: To be clear, it's the _signal_ that's dropping out, not the _person_.

Comment: That said, "I'm dropping out" can work perfectly fine in context.

Comment: Yeah; "You're breaking up, I think I'm about to drop out". People understand the other person isn't *falling apart*